# Computing limit

Tags: limits

I want to prove the following:

Let $p > 2$, then

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log(n)^{1/p}\log\log(n)^{2/p}}{\log(n)^{1/2}} = 0$

For $p\leq 2$ the statement is obviously false, but for $p > 2$ I guess the statement holds.
I tried to apply L'Hosptial's rule over and over, but someone I didn't manage to get a solution; so I tend to guess there is another way to prove the statement. Are there any proven statements about the behavior of $\log\log(n)$ that might be helpful here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know I'm a little late, but have you tried substituting log(n)? As $n$ approaches $\infty$, $\log(n)$ also approaches $\infty$, so you could just replace $\log(n)$ with $n$

Answer (score 0):

(I couldn't post this as a comment because I don't have enough reputation)

I graphed this function on Desmos, and apparently, your limit is zero when it approaches 10, not $\infty$ (unless I graphed the wrong function, here's what I have: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ock9ayyrzs).

Answer (score 0):

The statement indeed holds true. Just write

$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\log(n)^{1/p}\log\log(n)^{2/p}}{\log(n)^{1/2}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log(n)^{1/p}}{\log(n)^{1/p}}\frac{\log\log(n)^{2/p}}{\log(n)^{1/2 - 1/p}}$

The statement follows now by the fact that
$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\log\log(n)}{\log(n)^\varepsilon} = 0$
for any $\varepsilon > 0$, which itself can be obtained by applying L'Hospital just once.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).